# Background Color doesn't change while changing windows system colors

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu, background-color, system-tray

with the following code I get an system tray icon with context menu. But when I change the windows theme while the application is running, than the background color stays unchanged.

```
private System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon notifyIcon1;
    private System.Windows.Controls.ContextMenu contextMenu1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem menuItem1;
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components;


    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        Action action = new Action(ExecuteStartupSequence);
        action.ExecuteProfiled();


        this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
        /*
        this.contextMenu1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenu();
        this.menuItem1 = new System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem();
         */

        // Initialize contextMenu1
        /*
        this.contextMenu1.MenuItems.AddRange(
                    new System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem[] { this.menuItem1 });
        */

        // Initialize menuItem1
        /*
        this.menuItem1.Index = 0;
        this.menuItem1.Text = "E&xit";
        this.menuItem1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.menuItem1_Click);
        */
        this.contextMenu1 = this.FindResource("TrayContextMenu") as System.Windows.Controls.ContextMenu;


        // Create the NotifyIcon.
        //this.notifyIcon1 = new System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon(this.components);
        this.notifyIcon1 = new System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon(components);

        // The Icon property sets the icon that will appear
        // in the systray for this application.
        notifyIcon1.Icon = new System.Drawing.Icon("Icon1.ico");

        // The ContextMenu property sets the menu that will
        // appear when the systray icon is right clicked.
        // notifyIcon1.ContextMenu = this.contextMenu1;

        // The Text property sets the text that will be displayed,
        // in a tooltip, when the mouse hovers over the systray icon.
        notifyIcon1.Text = "Form1 (NotifyIcon example)";
        notifyIcon1.Visible = true;

        // Handle the DoubleClick event to activate the form.
        notifyIcon1.DoubleClick += new System.EventHandler(this.notifyIcon1_DoubleClick);
        notifyIcon1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.notifyIcon1_DoubleClick);



        //tb = (TaskbarIcon)FindResource("notifyIcon"); ;
    }

    private void notifyIcon1_DoubleClick(object Sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.contextMenu1 = this.FindResource("TrayContextMenu") as System.Windows.Controls.ContextMenu;
        contextMenu1.IsOpen = true;
    }

    private void menuItem1_Click(object Sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Open");


    }
```

And here the XAML-Stuff.

```
<ContextMenu x:Key="TrayContextMenu" Placement="MousePoint" Style="{x:Null}">
        <MenuItem Header="First Menu Item" Style="{x:Null}" />
        <MenuItem Header="Second Menu Item" Style="{x:Null}" />
        </ContextMenu>
        <Popup x:Key="TrayPopup" Placement="MousePoint">
            <Border Width="100" Height="100" Background="White" BorderBrush="Orange" BorderThickness="4">
            <Button Content="Close" Click="menuItem1_Click"></Button>
            </Border>
        </Popup>
```

I can't understand this, I already use Style="{x:Null}", to get rid of all miss configured stuff, but it simply doesn't work. May I have to avoid using System.Windows.Controls.Contextmenu, but what should I use instead?

I'm thankful for all hints.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get color changed when you change windows colors, than your control need to use  one of the system colors [System colors in wpf](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpf/archive/2010/11/30/systemcolors-reference.aspx)

Then use dynamicresource in order to reapply resource when it get changed

```
 <Border Width="100" Height="100" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't help.

Comment: I find out, that it works, if the context menu is visible, when the windows system colors will be changed.

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the affected XAML-code to:

```
<ContextMenu 
        x:Key="TrayContextMenu" 
        Placement="MousePoint" 
        Style="{x:Null}" 
        Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}">
        <MenuItem 
            Header="First Menu Item" 
            Style="{x:Null}"
            Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/>

        <MenuItem 
            Header="Second Menu Item" 
            Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}" />

        </ContextMenu>
        <Popup x:Key="TrayPopup" Placement="MousePoint">
            <Border Width="100" Height="100" Background="White" BorderBrush="Orange" BorderThickness="4">
            <Button Content="Close" Click="menuItem1_Click"></Button>
            </Border>
        </Popup>
```

But the result was still the same.

Normally this would solve the problem, but in case of an trayicon contextmenu it fails.